# Reading files from specific folder and show them in recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mediastore

I have fetched all my PDF files from external storage and showed them in my app recycler view but now I have a problem. I want to fetch all pdf files from some specific folder and show them in the recycler view of my app. Is there any possible way to fetch from a specific directory?

This function will be completely fine and fetch all files from storage but I don't want to fetch all from external storage, I want to do it from some specific directory.
This function will give me the list of all pdf files in my external storage.
I want to make some changes to this function but I don't know how.

```
/**
 * reading SD card from this function
 *
 */
private List<PdfModel> ReadSDcard()
{
    List<PdfModel> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED
    };


    final String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE +" = ?";
    String pdf = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{pdf};

    Uri collection;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
//        collection = MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri("external");
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
//        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL+"/"+"Abbas_1122");
        Log.e(TAG, "ReadSDcard: path______________________________________________"+collection );
        myList.addAll( getListOfPdfFiles(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs));
    }
    else
    {
//        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myFolder_1122/");  _________"myFolder_1122" this is the folder which i have created
//        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");//this will work for fetching all files from external below API level 30
        collection = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("//media//storage/emulated/0/Abbas_1122/");//this will work for fetching all files from external below API level 30
        Log.e(TAG, "ReadSDcard: path ______________________________________________ "+collection );
        Toast.makeText(this, "collection: "+collection.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        myList.addAll( getListOfPdfFiles(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs));

    }
    return myList;
}


    private List<PdfModel> getListOfPdfFiles(Uri collection, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectArgs)
    {
        List<PdfModel> pdfList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(collection, projection,selection, selectArgs,null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int columIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
                do {
                    try {
                        File file = new File(cursor.getString(columIndex));
                        String fileName = file.getName();
                        PdfModel pdfModel = new PdfModel(fileName, "129", 0, "pdf", file.getPath());
                        pdfList.add(pdfModel);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pdfList;
    }
```

Comment: I already told you how to do that but you removed your post and did not give the info asked for. That is not the way to solve problems or to use stackoverflow.

Comment: i havent removed my post brother... its already there but i cannot edit it thats why i post it again

Comment: please read this post i cannot solve the problem

Comment: Is it there? Then why cant i find it? Please post a link.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Problem it was very easy but i didn't know why my mind isn't working on that...
First you have to ask a permissions from user, like read and write External storage and also you have to ask Manage external storage and also you have to add in manifist application section you have to add this bellow line...

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"



private void fn_permission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
        }

        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    } else {
        boolean_permission = true;
    }
}
```

if the users have grants the permission then the following function will give you a list of pdf files

```
/**
 * reading from specific folder in Android */
private List<PdfModel> readFilesFromSpecificDir()
{
    List<PdfModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    File filePath = new File(getDefaultStorageLocation());
    File[] fileList = filePath.listFiles();
    assert fileList != null;
    if (fileList.length!=0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<fileList.length; i++)
        {       //I have pdf model which will take these five arguments so you 
                   have to make your own
            list.add(new PdfModel(fileList[i].getName(),"123", 1.12, "pdf", fileList[i].getPath()));
            Log.e(TAG, "readFilesFromSpecificDir: wroking  list of files are given bellow ______________________________________________"+fileList[i].getName().toString() );
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "List empty...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return list;
}
//Doc_Reader
    public String getDefaultStorageLocation()  {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/YourFolderName/");
        Log.e(TAG, "getDefaultStorageLocation: __________________________________"+dir );
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = dir.mkdir();
            if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity() , "Directory cannot be created", 
                strong textToast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Error", "Directory could not be created");
            }
        }
    return dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/";
}
```

in the question i have been trying to use the content resolver for fetching the specific folder to fetch or retrieve their files and show them in my app recycler view... but i have failed So this method is working on before the Api leve 30 or after the api level 30.... but make sure you have been alowed the permissions
Specially thanks @blackapps for taking interst and reply me to solve my Problem

Comment: Manage external permission will not allow play store